# How to use (Grunt) BrowserSync to serve files 1 level deeper than server root & maintain links?

Tags: node.js, indexing, gruntjs

My projects are structured like so:

`/root src files
 |_ /public
     |_ /html
         |_ index.html
         |_ about.html
         |_ contact.html
     |_ /css
     |_ /js
     |_ index.php`

Where all of the src files: html templates, Sass & raw JS scripts are in the root, and get published to the relevant folders in public.

I "build" everything in plain HTML first to test the functionality & flow, with links in html files just plain, relative filenames (e.g. `<a href="about.html">`). I set my server to serve from the /public directory, and without BrowserSync, would browse to localhost/builds/ to test.

However, when using BrowserSync, setting `--server` to `public` and `--index` to `builds/index.html` loads the index at localhost:3000, but actually, all files need to be accessed through localhost:3000/builds.

This means that none of the links in the html files work, because they all just point to localhost:3000, so 404. I can't set BrowserSync to serve from /html because then the CSS & JS paths are incorrect.

Is there any way around this without moving the html files to the root of /public?